# how to create a trigger for specific database in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySql 5.5 database and i have test1,test2,test3 and test4 databases.
test1 database have 3 tables(Student,Employee,Trainer).
test2 database have 3 tables(table1,table2,table3).
Now my Question is

How to apply TRIGGER for test1 database ? so hear the TRIGGER is applied for  Student,Employee,Trainer tables.

Please give me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The general syntax of CREATE TRIGGER is :
  CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW trigger_statement**

in the following example we are updating the Salary column of Employee table before inserting any record in Emp table. Example :

mysql> SELECT * FROM Employee;

+-----+---------+----------+-------------------+--------+-------+

**| Eid | Ename   | City     | Designation       | Salary | Perks |**

+-----+---------+----------+-------------------+--------+-------+

| 1   | Rahul   | Delhi    | Manager           | 10300  | 853   |

| 2   | Gaurav  | Mumbai   | Assistant Manager | 10300  | 853   |

| 3   | Chandan | Banglore | Team Leader       | 15450  | 999   |

| 5   | Tapan   | Pune     | Developer         | 20600  | 1111  |

| 6   | Amar    | Chennai  | Developer         | 16000  | 1124  |

| 7   | Santosh | Delhi    | Designer          | 10000  | 865   |

| 8   | Suman   | Pune     | Web Designer      | 20000  | 658   |

+-----+---------+----------+-------------------+--------+-------+

7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter //

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER ins_trig BEFORE INSERT ON Emp

```
-> FOR EACH ROW

-> BEGIN

-> UPDATE Employee SET Salary=Salary-300 WHERE Perks>500;

-> END;

-> //
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> INSERT INTO Emp VALUES(9,'Rajesh','Delhi','Developer',15000,658);

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Employee;

+-----+---------+----------+-------------------+--------+-------+

**| Eid | Ename   | City     | Designation       | Salary | Perks |**

+-----+---------+----------+-------------------+--------+-------+

| 1   | Rahul   | Delhi    | Manager           | 10000  | 853   |

| 2   | Gaurav  | Mumbai   | Assistant Manager | 10000  | 853   |

| 3   | Chandan | Banglore | Team Leader       | 15150  | 999   |

| 5   | Tapan   | Pune     | Developer         | 20300  | 1111  |

| 6   | Amar    | Chennai  | Developer         | 15700  | 1124  |

| 7   | Santosh | Delhi    | Designer          | 9700   | 865   |

| 8   | Suman   | Pune     | Web Designer      | 19700  | 658   |

+-----+---------+----------+-------------------+--------+-------+

7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: it is possible to apply?                                       CREATE TRIGGER test.ins_trig BEFORE INSERT ON test.table1,test.table2

-> FOR EACH ROW

-> BEGIN

-> UPDATE Employee SET Salary=Salary-300 WHERE Perks>500;

-> END;

-> //

Answer (score 0):

You create a trigger on a particular table in a particular database.

See [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to see how this is done.

Comment: I have the Knowledge to apply Trigger for each table in database.. but i want to create a trigger for each database not for each table.. so it is possible or not?

Comment: @user1557627 - That does not make any sense. Triggers occur when an operation (insert, delete, update) occurs on a particular table.